# Здравствуйте. Подскажите почему письмо из формы обратной связи не доходит до нужного email адреса? Прикрепляю форму html и скрипт php

Tags: php, backend

```html
<form action='http://vvlsmd9t.beget.tech/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B.html?' method="POST" class="quote">
  <div>
    <label>Имя</label><br>
    <input name="имя" type="text" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Email</label><br>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Emial Address">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Вопрос</label><br>
    <textarea name="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="button_1" type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>



<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Acme Web Deisgn |Контакты</title>
  <!-- Через 10 секунд после появления сообщения об отправке или ошибке — отправляемся на сайт Кода :) -->
  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10; url=http://thecode.local/'>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <!-- Начался блок PHP -->
  <?php
    // Получаем значения переменных из пришедших данных
    $name = $_POST[ 'name' ];
    $email = $_POST[ 'email' ];
    $message = $_POST[ 'text' ];
    // Формируем сообщение для отправки, в нём мы соберём всё, что ввели в форме
    $mes = "Имя: $name \nE-mail: $email \nТекст: $message";
    // Пытаемся отправить письмо по заданному адресу
    // Если нужно, чтобы письма всё время уходили на ваш адрес — замените первую переменную $email на свой адрес электронной почты
    $send = mail( $kilion74 @yandex . ru, $mes, "Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8\r\nFrom:$email" );
    // Если отправка прошла успешно — так и пишем
    if ( $send == 'true' ) {
      echo "Сообщение отправлено";
    }
    // Если письмо не ушло — выводим сообщение об ошибке
    else {
      echo "Ой, что-то пошло не так";
    }
    ?>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А адрес получателя так и должен выглядеть, с знаком доллара в начале и с пробелами? `$kilion74 @yandex . ru`, вторым параметром должен быть subject, а не сообщение, сообщение соответсвенно должно быть третьим параметром, а заголовки четвертым. И почему в action формы html файла, а не PHP?

Comment: у вас, скорее всего, не настроена функция mail. Воспользуйтесь библиотекой для отправки почты по smtp